# Sort author list alphabetically

Tags: php, sort

I have narrowed the code down to this:

```
<?php
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM '.$wpdb->posts);
    if($authors):
    foreach($authors as $author):

    ?>
```

I would like the authors to be sorted Alphabetically, it doesn't matter if it sorts by first name, last name.

Comment: What do you want as an end result?  A list of names, a list of author ids?

Comment: A list of names

Answer (score 0):

Your Query gets the authors ID and is you want them sorted Alphabetically you will need to get the author(user object) so try:

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM '.$wpdb->posts);
if($authors){
    $users = get_users( array(
        'include' => $authors,
        'orderby' =>  'display_name'
    ));
    foreach ((array)$users as $user) {
       echo '<li>' . $user->display_name. '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no tag in the answer so your problem is not comming from here